# KMail add personal information into template

Tags: linux, email, kde, kubuntu, kmail

I want to create template in KMail:
`[Settings]->[Configure KMail]->[Identities]->[Modify]->[Templates]` for sending message with footer like this:

```
Best regards,
<First Name> <Second Name>
<Job position>
<Organization>
```

and I want these **First Name**, **Second Name** and **Organization** was used from **"General"** tab, where I filled these fields **"Your name:"**, **"Organization"**, **"Email address"** and put into template.

**Question:** How I could do that? Is any how-to's and documents about using templates in **Kmail** application?

Answer (score 0):

If you have filled "Your name:" field in "General" tab, like so:

```
Your name: Jon Bullet
```

and **John** is the first name, **Bullet** is the second, so template is the following:

```
%CURSOR
Best regards,
%OFROMNAME
Software Engineer
Berlin Tech Company
```

or

```
%CURSOR
Best regards,
%OFROMFNAME %OFROMLNAME
Software Engineer
Berlin Tech Company
```

Where

1. **%OFROMNAME** is the full name written in the mentioned field
2. **%OFROMFNAME** is the first name
3. **%OFROMLNAME** is the second name
4. **%CURSOR** will put your cursor on this place, in our case at the beginning of the new line